# Multiple index search in Kibana and plot common values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have some data which is separated for organizational purposes into two separate indexes with the same key value mappings (although some that exist in index B do not exist in index A).  I know in Kibana 4 I can now query multiple indexes at the same time.  What I want to do is plot document data where a field exists in both index A and index B.

My use case is I have source IP data from application A and source IP data from application B.  What I want to do is make Kibana graphs showing counts of where the source IP exists in both indexes to track common IP traffic between both applications.

Is this doable? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: How do you identify these different documents from different index as same? Are the docID the same or is there some other criteria ?

Comment: Good question. There is a common key value pair between the two (in this case, source_ip).

Comment: Were you able to figure this ?